# Golang slices of struct or newbie trouble building REST

Tags: json, postgresql, rest, go, go-gin

and need your help.
Wanted to build simple api and stuck with some problem.
I've choose [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) and database/sql with [postgres driver](https://www.postgresql.org/)

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/search/:text", SearchWord)
    router.Run(":8080")

}
```

I need to make query to DB and make json out of this request.

```
func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type Message struct {
    ticket_id int    `json:"ticket_id"`
    event     string `json:"event"`
}

func SearchWord(c *gin.Context) {
    word := c.Params.ByName("text")
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=8.8.8.8 user= password= dbname=sample")
    defer db.Close()
    checkErr(err)
    rows, err2 := db.Query("SELECT ticket_id,event FROM ....$1, word)
    checkErr(err)
    for rows.Next() {
        var ticket_id int
        var event string
        err = rows.Scan(&ticket_id, &event)
        checkErr(err)
        fmt.Printf("%d | %s \n\n", ticket_id, event)
    }

}
```

This coda working nice, but when i need to make json.
I need to make struct of a row

```
type Message struct {
    ticket_id int    `json:"ticket_id"`
    event     string `json:"event"`
}
```

an then i need to create slice , and append every rows.Next() loop an than answer to browser with Json...

```
c.JSON(200, messages)
```

But how to do that...don't know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to cheat a little here and fix a few things along the way:

First: open your database connection pool once at program start-up (and not on every request).

Second: we'll use [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) to make it easier to marshal our database rows into our struct.

```go
package main

var db *sqlx.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    // sqlx.Connect also checks that the connection works.
    // sql.Open only "establishes" a pool, but doesn't ping the DB.
    db, err = sqlx.Connect("postgres", "postgres:///...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/search/:text", SearchWord)
    router.Run(":8080")

}

// in_another_file.go

type Message struct {
    TicketID int    `json:"ticket_id" db:"ticket_id"`
    Event     string `json:"event" db:"event"`
}

func SearchWord(c *gin.Context) {
    word := c.Params.ByName("text")
    // We create a slice of structs to marshal our rows into
    var messages []*Message{}
    // Our DB connection pool is safe to use concurrently from here
    err := db.Select(&messages, "SELECT ticket_id,event FROM ....$1, word)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(c.Writer, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // Write it out using gin-gonic's JSON writer.
    c.JSON(200, messages)
}
```

I hope that's clear. `sqlx` also takes care of calling `rows.Close()` for you, which will otherwise leave connections hanging.

Comment: messages := []*Message makes "syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting {"
I made it with"var messages []*Message"
But now get error when db.Select error handlind "non-struct dest type struct with >1 columns (2)"

Comment: How many items are you selecting? If it's just one you only need a `Message` — if it's more you'll need a `[]*Message`.

Comment: error with select was because i need to make uppercase variable like @inf said. thx a lot 4 answers

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer: I am brand new to go

Since you `Scan`ned your column data into your variables, you should be able to initialize a structure with their values:

`m := &Message{ticket_id: ticket_id, event: event}`

You could initialize a slice with

`s := make([]*Message, 0)`

And then append each of your message structs after instantiation:

`s = append(s, m)`

---

Because I'm not too familiar with go there are a couple things i'm not sure about:

- after copying data from query to your vars using `rows.Scan` does initializing the `Message` struct copy the current iterations values as expected??
- If there is a way to get the total number of rows from your query it might be slighlty more performant to initialize a static length array, instead of a slice?
- I think @inf deleted answer about marshalling your `Message` to json down the line might need to be addressed, and `Message` field's might need to be capitalized

copied from @inf:

> The names of the members of your struct need be capitalized so that
>   they get exported and can be accessed.
>
> ```
> type Message struct {
>     Ticket_id int    `json:"ticket_id"`
>     Event     string `json:"event"` }
> ```

Comment: If you know the number of rows you want it can be more performant to `make([]Message, 15)` where 15 is the number of rows.